# Python 3.6 SSL - Uses TLSv1.0 instead of TLSv1.2 cipher - (2 way auth and self-signed cert)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I'm using the ssl library with python 3.6. I'm using self-signed ECDSA certificate that I generated with openssl.

**Server/client code:**

```
# Create a context in TLSv1.2, requiring a certificate (2-way auth)
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1
context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.check_hostname = True # This line ommited in server code

# Set the list of allowed ciphers to those with key length of at least 128
# TODO Figure out why this isn't working
context.set_ciphers('TLSv1.2+HIGH+SHA256+ECDSA')

# Print some info about the connection
for cipher in context.get_ciphers():
    print(cipher)
```

Output:

```
{'id': 50380835, 'name': 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256', 'protocol': 'TLSv1/SSLv3', 'description': 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256', 'strength_bits': 128, 'alg_bits': 128}
```

The current cipher:

```
 connection.cipher()
```

('ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256', 'TLSv1/SSLv3', 128)

My question: why is the selected cipher not TLSv1.2?

**Edit: Requested screenshots**

[image]

[image]

Based on another thread, I tried changing my code to the following, without any success.

```
 # Create a context in TLSv1.2, requiring a certificate (2-way auth)
    self.context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    self.context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_SSLv2
    self.context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3
    self.context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1
    self.context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1
    self.context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
    # self.context.check_hostname = True

    # Set the list of allowed ciphers to those with high key length
    # I went with  SHA384 because it seemed to have more security
    self.context.set_ciphers('TLSv1.2+ECDSA+HIGH')
```

Answer (score 1):

This cipher is compatible with TLS 1.2, it's an ordinary cipher defined in [RFC 5289](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5289).

I think we need to interpret somewhat Python's doc to know what get_ciphers() is returning exactly as it's not explained. But cipher() gives us the answer maybe :

> SSLSocket.cipher()
>
> Returns a three-value tuple containing the name of the cipher being used, **the version of the SSL protocol that defines its use**, and
> the number of secret bits being used. If no connection has been
> established, returns None.

A network capture would confirm the TLS protocol version.

Comment: Added some screenshots. It seems to be using ssh! Doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: SSL traffic is usually on port 443, you could try capturing on this port only. If it's working, open the capture and go on the Client Hello packet.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`SSLSocket.version()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html?#ssl.SSLSocket.version)

---

Following on from Eugène Adell's answer, as to why `SSLSocket.cipher()` isn't giving you what you expect, python [calls](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Modules/_ssl.c#L1677) [`SSL_CIPHER_get_version()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/SSL_CIPHER_get_name.html), whose documentation says:

> ... returns string which indicates the SSL/TLS protocol version that first defined the cipher. This is currently SSLv2 or TLSv1/SSLv3. In some cases it should possibly return "TLSv1.2" but does not; use SSL_CIPHER_description() instead.